# Reading csv file with fields in double quotes as structure

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, csv, c#-3.0

I want to read a CSV file using [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) with with the filed in double quotes and seperated with commas as the struture. How to get field values without double quotes after reading.

CSV struture is

"val1","val2","val3"
"val4","val5","val6"

converted to
val1,val2,val3
val4,val5,val6

Comment: After reading you can have the string replace of \" with string.empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace all " with empty string.

```
 string yourCSVString; // "\"var1\",\"var2\",\"var3\"";
 string processedString;
 processedString=yourCSVString.Replace("\"","");
 Console.WriteLine(processedString);
```

Hope it helps.